# Laravel: How I can remove inner arrays from my collection?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get the products that are ordered most often. I can get products from all orders this way:

```
$orders = $business->orders()->with('products')->get();
$subset = $orders->map(function ($order) {
      return $order->products->map(function ($product) {
             return collect($product);
      });
});
return $subset;
```

It returns me the next response:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": "94567311-e669-4943-b90e-537669099bc2",
            "business_order_id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
            "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Black Tote Bag",
            "description": "Small",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Size",
            "variation_value_1": "Small",
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1500,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1500,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
            "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": "94567311-e6bb-48b4-8bdf-ad282dcc6d72",
            "business_order_id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
            "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-7781-4d9a-859e-8296669a9926",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Black Tote Bag",
            "description": "Medium",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Size",
            "variation_value_1": "Medium",
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1500,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1500,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
            "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "94606929-ad05-4c67-9491-644e8d3b434b",
            "business_order_id": "94606929-ab27-49c1-b8da-21cefee04e7a",
            "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Black Tote Bag",
            "description": "Small",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Size",
            "variation_value_1": "Small",
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1500,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1500,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
            "created_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": "94606929-ad66-4a69-93ae-1e291c2d7e53",
            "business_order_id": "94606929-ab27-49c1-b8da-21cefee04e7a",
            "business_product_id": "93253bf2-ce63-4a9a-b4a6-8ecaff439028",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Bynd Artisan Tote Bag Duplicate",
            "description": "Blue / Small",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Color",
            "variation_value_1": "Blue",
            "variation_key_2": "Size",
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 2000,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 2000,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "93253bf2-e5c2-4a22-8605-81c245bcf86b",
            "created_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "94606a50-2bac-48b8-860f-eebec27aff8d",
            "business_order_id": "94606a50-2a40-476e-bd71-50c096270174",
            "business_product_id": "93253bf2-ce63-4a9a-b4a6-8ecaff439028",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Bynd Artisan Tote Bag Duplicate",
            "description": "Blue / Small",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Color",
            "variation_value_1": "Blue",
            "variation_key_2": "Size",
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 2000,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 2000,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "93253bf2-e5c2-4a22-8605-81c245bcf86b",
            "created_at": "2021-09-12 11:43:34",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-12 11:43:34",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "9466c9d9-3131-43f7-99f3-c41ccd3308d1",
            "business_order_id": "9466c9d9-2a57-4551-b36b-294b64fb9fe4",
            "business_product_id": "93253bf2-ce63-4a9a-b4a6-8ecaff439028",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Bynd Artisan Tote Bag Duplicate",
            "description": "Blue / Small",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Color",
            "variation_value_1": "Blue",
            "variation_key_2": "Size",
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 2000,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 2000,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "93253bf2-e5c2-4a22-8605-81c245bcf86b",
            "created_at": "2021-09-15 15:45:40",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-15 15:45:40",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "9466dab9-cff6-4446-8729-2260ffe683a5",
            "business_order_id": "9466dab9-ccb5-4079-ad26-e76f5999164f",
            "business_product_id": "93253bf2-ce63-4a9a-b4a6-8ecaff439028",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Bynd Artisan Tote Bag Duplicate",
            "description": "Blue / Small",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Color",
            "variation_value_1": "Blue",
            "variation_key_2": "Size",
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 2000,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 2000,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "93253bf2-e5c2-4a22-8605-81c245bcf86b",
            "created_at": "2021-09-15 16:32:51",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-15 16:32:51",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": "9466dab9-d04d-454e-b6ce-889f2f0ce2ba",
            "business_order_id": "9466dab9-ccb5-4079-ad26-e76f5999164f",
            "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Black Tote Bag",
            "description": "Small",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Size",
            "variation_value_1": "Small",
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1500,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1500,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
            "created_at": "2021-09-15 16:32:51",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-15 16:32:51",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "94f1443b-4bfd-474c-b7a7-1cf20e0c0acd",
            "business_order_id": "94f14437-044c-48ae-8029-21ac712fa112",
            "business_product_id": "94cf74c8-453a-45e2-a292-b8e3a57953ff",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Testt",
            "description": null,
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": null,
            "variation_value_1": null,
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1000,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1000,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": null,
            "created_at": "2021-11-23 11:52:07",
            "updated_at": "2021-11-23 11:52:07",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": "94f1443e-a36f-4057-a995-38e9c39910f6",
            "business_order_id": "94f14437-044c-48ae-8029-21ac712fa112",
            "business_product_id": "93c98a41-ce98-44ec-864f-cdce5b37a5f9",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "yoyo toyyy",
            "description": null,
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": null,
            "variation_value_1": null,
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1200,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1200,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "94cf7aa4-0a9d-4bf6-ae43-ca71ce39eff0",
            "created_at": "2021-11-23 11:52:09",
            "updated_at": "2021-11-23 11:52:09",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ]
]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get response without inner arrays, so I can just group collection by `business_product_id`  and count how many there are of each product.

Any advice will be helpful, thanks!

UPD: Some clarifications:
In my app there are several businesses, each business can have multiple orders, and each order can have multiple products. In order to get all business orders including products (relation) I use `$orders = $business->orders()->with('products')->get();` I need to calculate the quantity how often the product is ordered, in other words, the number of times I see each product in my orders

Another UPD: I got the proper response of what I wanted:

```
{
    "93253bf2-ce63-4a9a-b4a6-8ecaff439028": {
        "product": {
            "id": "94606929-ad66-4a69-93ae-1e291c2d7e53",
            "business_order_id": "94606929-ab27-49c1-b8da-21cefee04e7a",
            "business_product_id": "93253bf2-ce63-4a9a-b4a6-8ecaff439028",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Bynd Artisan Tote Bag Duplicate",
            "description": "Blue / Small",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Color",
            "variation_value_1": "Blue",
            "variation_key_2": "Size",
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 2000,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 2000,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "93253bf2-e5c2-4a22-8605-81c245bcf86b",
            "created_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        "count": 4
    },
    "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338": {
        "product": {
            "id": "94567311-e669-4943-b90e-537669099bc2",
            "business_order_id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
            "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Black Tote Bag",
            "description": "Small",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Size",
            "variation_value_1": "Small",
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1500,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1500,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
            "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        "count": 3
    },
    "92df0ca8-7781-4d9a-859e-8296669a9926": {
        "product": {
            "id": "94567311-e6bb-48b4-8bdf-ad282dcc6d72",
            "business_order_id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
            "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-7781-4d9a-859e-8296669a9926",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Black Tote Bag",
            "description": "Medium",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Size",
            "variation_value_1": "Medium",
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1500,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1500,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
            "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        "count": 1
    },
    "94cf74c8-453a-45e2-a292-b8e3a57953ff": {
        "product": {
            "id": "94f1443b-4bfd-474c-b7a7-1cf20e0c0acd",
            "business_order_id": "94f14437-044c-48ae-8029-21ac712fa112",
            "business_product_id": "94cf74c8-453a-45e2-a292-b8e3a57953ff",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Testt",
            "description": null,
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": null,
            "variation_value_1": null,
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1000,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1000,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": null,
            "created_at": "2021-11-23 11:52:07",
            "updated_at": "2021-11-23 11:52:07",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        "count": 1
    },
    "93c98a41-ce98-44ec-864f-cdce5b37a5f9": {
        "product": {
            "id": "94f1443e-a36f-4057-a995-38e9c39910f6",
            "business_order_id": "94f14437-044c-48ae-8029-21ac712fa112",
            "business_product_id": "93c98a41-ce98-44ec-864f-cdce5b37a5f9",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "yoyo toyyy",
            "description": null,
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": null,
            "variation_value_1": null,
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1200,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1200,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "94cf7aa4-0a9d-4bf6-ae43-ca71ce39eff0",
            "created_at": "2021-11-23 11:52:09",
            "updated_at": "2021-11-23 11:52:09",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

And my final code looks like this:

```
$orders = $business->orders()->with('products')->get();

        foreach ($orders as $order){
            foreach ($order->products as $product)
                $subset[] = $product;
        }

        $groupedOrderedProducts = collect($subset)->groupBy('business_product_id');

        $withCount = $groupedOrderedProducts->map(function ($product){
            return ['product' => $product->first(),'count'=>$product->count()];
        })->sortByDesc('count');
```

But I believe it's not the best solution, any idea of how I can improve my code?

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow. i do curious as of why did you use `map` and `collect` if you wanted to get "most ordered" items? how do you define "most ordered"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @BagusTesa in my app there are several businesses, each business can have multiple orders, each order can have multiple products. In order to get all business's order including products (relation) I use 
`$orders = $business->orders()->with('products')->get();`
I need to calculate the quantity how often the product is ordered, in other words the number of times I see each product in my orders

Comment: @BagusTesa if you have another idea how I can achieve that without map and collect, please share that with me, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: hi Alena, people could vaguely guess the table structure. however, it would be superb if you could provide the table structure too. only the related part should be sufficient (e.g. quantity column from order, the relationship between order and product, etc).

Comment: @BagusTesa I understand, but we don't need to take quantity of ordered products into account, just frequency of ordering specific products. Please see my updated question, I finally achieved the result of what I wanted. But it seems that my code could be better

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$subset = $orders->map(function ($order) {
        return $order->products;
    })->groupBy('business_product_id');
```

Or in the continuation of your code:

```
$subset = collect($subset)->flatten()->groupBy('business_product_id');
```

Comment: None of this worked. The first option returned me the same response as I had another one the next:
```
{
    "": [
        "94567311-e669-4943-b90e-537669099bc2",
        "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
        "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338",
        null,
        "Black Tote Bag",
        "Small",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Size",
        "Small",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        1,
        null,
        "0.0000",
       .....
    ]
}
```